# How to access *.properties file in Seam application

Tags: java, properties, seam, seam2

Is there a way to access properties files in seam app? I'm looking for some kind of resource loader..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually Seam native component - ResourceLoader which can be simply injected with @In and it gives an access to the property files via ResourceBundle.

Example:

```
import org.jboss.seam.core.ResourceLoader;
... 
@In
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
...
resourceLoader.getResource("BUNDLE_NAME");
```

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://seamframework.org/Community/ReadPropertiesFromSeampropertiesForUnitTestWithTestNG) from the official seam forum may help you.